# How to create Azure databricks cluster using Service Principal

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I have azure databricks workspace and I added service principal in that workspace using databricks cli. I have been trying to create cluster using service principal and not able to figure it. Can any help me?

I am able to create cluster using my account but I want to create using Service Principal and want it to be the owner of the cluster not me.
Also, it there a way I can transfer the ownership of my cluster to Service Principal?

Answer (score 1):

First, answering the second question - no, you can't change the owner of the cluster.

To create a cluster that will have Service Principal as owner you need to execute creation operation under its identity. To do this you need to perform following steps:

- Prepare a JSON file with cluster definition as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters#--create)
- Set `DATABRICKS_HOST` environment variable to an address of your workspace:

```sh
export DATABRICKS_HOST=https://adb-....azuredatabricks.net
```

- Generate AAD token for Service principal as described in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token) and assign its value to `DATABRICKS_TOKEN` or `DATABRICKS_AAD_TOKEN` environment variables (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/)).
- Create Databricks cluster using databricks-cli providing name of JSON file with cluster specification ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/clusters-cli#create-a-cluster)):

```sh
databricks clusters create --json-file create-cluster.json
```

P.S. Another approach (really recommended) is to use [Databricks Terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs) to script your Databricks infrastructure - it's used by significant number of Databricks customers, and much easier to use compared with command-line tools.

Comment: You advise to use Terraform to provision a cluster that has a service principal as owner. Do you also have a reference for how that is done in Terraform?

Comment: Just authenticate in terraform as service principal - it’s in the terraform provider docs